# How to target only tablet with width greater than 600

Tags: android

I Want to publish my android app only for the tablet having screen with greater than 600. I am using this code in manifest for this. Just want to confirm if it is correct?

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="false"
                  android:normalScreens="false"
                  android:largeScreens="false"
                  android:xlargeScreens="true"
                  android:requiresSmallestWidthDp="600" />
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To target your app only for 
Tablets running ICS or HOneycomb, do one more thing in your `Android Manifest`:

```
 <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
```

> - Users having Gingerbread (2.3) or below can't download your app (because, now your application is purely intended for Tablets).

`Points to Note`_

- HoneyComb Tablets (3.0) is supported (because <3.2 is ignoring the *requiresSmallestWidth* attribute)
- ICS Tablets are supported because it does look at your *smallestWidth* attribute
- and, finally ICS phones aren't because as we say ICS uses the *smallestWidth* attribute

this way your application is now get ready for all `Tablets` :)
for more please read [developer.android](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens-distribution.html#FilteringTabletApps).

I hope this will help you and all!